# How to solve the deployment issue about QT creator?

Tags: windows, qt

I am going to deploy the QT creator project. But I discovered that some functions of deployment .exe are missing. However, it originally works inside the QT creator. I have no idea about how to solve the current problem, like using what tools to help. The missing function is that the program doesn't show the thumbnails about the video files, where I have assigned the relative images to that.

filemodel.h

```
#ifndef FILEMODEL_H
#define FILEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <iostream>
#include <QImage>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

struct File
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER name)
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl url MEMBER url)
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage iconImg MEMBER iconImg)
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl urlicon MEMBER urlicon)

public:
    QString name;
    QUrl url;
    QImage iconImg;
    QUrl urlicon;
    File(const QString& name=""){
        //cout<<name.toStdString();

        this->name = QFileInfo(name).fileName();
        this->url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(name);
        int i = name.toStdString().find(".mp4");

        if(i<0)
        {
            this->urlicon = QUrl::fromLocalFile(name);
        }
        else{
            string temp = QFileInfo(name).fileName().toStdString();
            int j = temp.find(".mp4");
            //string str = "C:\\Video\\"+ temp.replace(j,4,".jpg");
            string str = "C:\\Video\\"+ temp.replace(j,4,".jpg");
            this->urlicon = QUrl::fromLocalFile(QString::fromStdString(str));
        }
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(File)

class FileModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    enum dashBoardRoles {
        NameRole=Qt::UserRole+1,
        URLRole,
        ICONRole,
        URLICONRole
    };
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString folder READ folder WRITE setFolder NOTIFY folderChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList nameFilters READ nameFilters WRITE setNameFilters NOTIFY nameFiltersChanged)

public:
    FileModel(QObject *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QAbstractListModel(parent){
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant get(int index){
        return QVariant::fromValue(m_all_dirs[index]);
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent=QModelIndex()) const{
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_all_dirs.count();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const{
        if(index.row()<0 && index.row()>= rowCount())
            return QVariant();
        File  file = m_all_dirs[index.row()];
        if(role == NameRole)
            return file.name;
        else if(role == URLRole)
            return file.url;
        else if(role == ICONRole)
            return file.iconImg;
        else if(role == URLICONRole)
            return file.urlicon;
        return QVariant();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
        QHash <int,QByteArray> roles;
        roles [NameRole]="fileName";
        roles [URLRole]="url";
        roles [ICONRole]="icon";
        roles [URLICONRole]="urlicon";
        return roles;
    }

    QString folder() const{
        return mFolder;
    }

    void setFolder(const QString &folder)
    {
        if(mFolder == folder)
            return;
        mFolder = folder;
        emit folderChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

    QStringList nameFilters() const{
        return mNameFilters;
    }

    void setNameFilters(const QStringList &nameFilters){
        if(mNameFilters == nameFilters)
            return;
        mNameFilters = nameFilters;
        emit nameFiltersChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

signals:
    void folderChanged();
    void nameFiltersChanged();

private:
    void findFiles(){

        beginResetModel();
        m_all_dirs.clear();

        if(QDir(mFolder).exists()){
            QFuture<QStringList> future = QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
                QStringList files;
                QDirIterator it(mFolder, mNameFilters, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
                while (it.hasNext()){
                    files<<it.next();
                }

                ofstream myfile;
                myfile.open (mFolder.toStdString()+"\\example.xml");
                myfile <<"<files>"<<"\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i)
                    myfile << "<"+ std::to_string(i) + ">"<< files.at(i).toStdString()<< "</"+ std::to_string(i) + ">" <<"\n";
                //
                myfile <<"</files>"<<"\n";
                myfile.close();

                for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i){
                    int j = files.at(i).toStdString().find(".mp4");
                    if(j>0)
                    {
                        VideoCapture cap(files.at(i).toStdString());
                        Mat frame;

                        cap >> frame;

                        string str = QFileInfo(files.at(i)).fileName().toStdString();
                        int k = str.find(".mp4");
                        str = "C:\\Video\\"+ str.replace(k,4,".jpg");
                        imwrite(str,frame);
                    }
                }

                return files;
            });
            QStringList fullNames = future.result();
            for(const QString& fullName: fullNames){
                File file{fullName};
                m_all_dirs << file;
            }
            //return 0;
        }
        endResetModel();
    }
    QString mFolder;
    QList<File> m_all_dirs;
    QStringList mNameFilters;
};

#endif // FILEMODEL_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "filemodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<FileModel>("com.contentplayermod.filemodel", 1,0, "FileModel");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.8
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import com.contentplayermod.filemodel 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id:main_win
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")
    property int idx: 0
    property bool isActive: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        playTimer.start()
        subWindow.show();
        subWindow.requestActivate();
        main_win.hide();
        playMusic(grid_main.currentIndex)
    }

     GridView {
                       id:grid_main
                       anchors.fill: parent
                       cellWidth: 100; cellHeight: 100
                       focus: true
                       currentIndex: 0

                       model: FileModel{
                           id: myModel
                           folder: "c:\\test2"//"/mnt/sdcard/app_pictureFrameImage"//
                           nameFilters: ["*.jpg" ,"*.mp4"]  //"*.mp4",
                       }

                       highlight: Rectangle { width: 80; height: 80; color: "lightsteelblue" }

                       delegate: Item {
                           width: 100; height: 100

                           Image {
                               id: myIcon
                               width: 30
                               height: 30
                               y: 20; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                               source: urlicon
                           }
                           Text {
                               anchors { top: myIcon.bottom; horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter }
                               text: fileName
                           }
                           MouseArea {
                               anchors.fill: parent
                               onClicked: {
                                   parent.GridView.view.currentIndex = index

                               }
                           }
                       }

                       Keys.onReturnPressed:{
                           playTimer.start()
                           subWindow.show();
                           subWindow.requestActivate();
                           playMusic(grid_main.currentIndex)
                           //subWindow.forceActiveFocus();
                           //event.accepted = true;
                           grid_main.focus = false;
                       }

                       /*
                       Keys.onPressed: {
                                if (event.key == 16777220) {//enter
                                    playTimer.start()
                                    subWindow.show();
                                    subWindow.requestActivate();
                                    playMusic(grid_main.currentIndex)
                                    //subWindow.forceActiveFocus();
                                    event.accepted = true;
                                    grid_main.focus = false;
                                    //main_win.hide();
                                }
                       }*/
    }


   Window {
           id: subWindow
           visible: true
           width: 640
           height: 480

          MediaPlayer {
              id: player
          }

          VideoOutput {
              id: video
              anchors.fill: parent
              source: player
          }

          Item {
               focus: true
               Keys.onReturnPressed:{

                   subWindow.close()
                   grid_main.forceActiveFocus();
                   main_win.show();
               }
           }
    }

    function playMusic(index){
        idx = index
        //player.stop()
        player.source = myModel.get(index).url
        player.play()
    }

    Timer {
        id: playTimer
        interval: 2000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            var source_name = player.source;

            if(source_name.toString().indexOf(".jpg")>0 || source_name.toString().indexOf(".bmp")>0 || source_name.toString().indexOf(".png")>0){ //processing .jpg
                if (idx + 1 < grid_main.count){
                    playMusic(idx + 1);
                }else{
                    idx = 0;
                    playMusic(idx);
                }
            }

            else if(source_name.toString().indexOf(".mp4")>0){ //processing .mp4
                if (player.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia){
                    if (idx + 1 < grid_main.count){
                        playMusic(idx + 1);
                    }else{
                        idx = 0;
                        playMusic(idx);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I capture the frame of video and save it into the jpg files using OpenCV. And then I use qml's qurl to read those images as thumbnails. But it doesn't work in deployment application.

Comment: I capture the frame by code and then read the specific folder for displaying the thumbnails. How can I debug using the deployment '.exe' file?

Comment: If you capture by code, so does the application save the image file correct after deployed?

Comment: Yes, it does. But they just cannot be read in deployment application.

Comment: Are you using the right relative path?You could add some code so it could write debug information into `.txt` file or use winDBG

Comment: I use a absolute path to handle.

Comment: Could you provide this part of your code?

Comment: I provided the code. I used OpenCV in "find file" function of filemodel.h to capture the frame and save them into (C:\\Video) folder. The file constructor in filemodel.h will read the thumbnail of video (C:\\Video). And then read them in urlicon in main.qml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166940/discussion-between-shihe-zhang-and-opfan).